# Asigning new random list to nested dictionary assigns last seen list to all

Tags: python, dictionary

As described in the title I'm trying to assign a dictionary with lists as values that are random to parent dictionary. An unexpected thing is that when I want to assign it to parent dictionary then I only get the latest dictionary assigned. Please see code example:

```
temp = {}
d = {}
for x in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        temp[i] = list(np.random.randint(10, size=10))
    print(x)
    print(temp)
    d[x] = temp
    print(d[x])
print("--------------------------")
print("The final dictionary: ", d)


0
{0: [1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 3, 8, 1, 5], 1: [6, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 5, 9, 7, 1], 2: [7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 8, 6, 0, 6, 0]}
{0: [1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 3, 8, 1, 5], 1: [6, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 5, 9, 7, 1], 2: [7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 8, 6, 0, 6, 0]}
1
{0: [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 2, 0], 1: [1, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 0, 8, 7, 9], 2: [8, 8, 4, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4]}
{0: [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 2, 0], 1: [1, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 0, 8, 7, 9], 2: [8, 8, 4, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4]}
2
{0: [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [5, 9, 7, 8, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9], 2: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]}
{0: [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [5, 9, 7, 8, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9], 2: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]}
--------------------------
The final dictionary:  {0: {0: [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [5, 9, 7, 8, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9], 2: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]}, 1: {0: [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [5, 9, 7, 8, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9], 2: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]}, 2: {0: [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [5, 9, 7, 8, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9], 2: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]}}
```

Comment: By the way, really great format of question! Example, as well as the debug prints show the effort you did solving it yourself! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that in the line `d[x] = temp` you are just referencing on the same object and when you overwrite temp, you also overwrite all existing links to it. The problem is called `shallow vs deep copy`. There are multiple ways, to create a 'real' copy, but the `copy library` offers two functions `copy, deepcopy` that do just that. Notice, for nested objects, you need the `deepcopy` function

```
from copy import copy


temp = {}
d = {}
for x in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        temp[i] = list(np.random.randint(10, size=10))
    print(x)
    print(temp)
    d[x] = copy(temp)

    print(d[x])
print("--------------------------")
print("The final dictionary: ", d)
```

```
{0: [2, 7, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9, 9, 4], 1: [1, 0, 1, 9, 6, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3], 2: [9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2]}
{0: [2, 7, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9, 9, 4], 1: [1, 0, 1, 9, 6, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3], 2: [9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2]}
1
{0: [3, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 9, 0, 6], 1: [4, 1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 3], 2: [7, 2, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5, 4, 6, 0]}
{0: [3, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 9, 0, 6], 1: [4, 1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 3], 2: [7, 2, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5, 4, 6, 0]}
2
{0: [0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 9], 1: [5, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 3], 2: [1, 6, 5, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4]}
{0: [0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 9], 1: [5, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 3], 2: [1, 6, 5, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4]}
--------------------------
The final dictionary:  {0: {0: [2, 7, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9, 9, 4], 1: [1, 0, 1, 9, 6, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3], 2: [9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2]}, 1: {0: [3, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 9, 0, 6], 1: [4, 1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 3], 2: [7, 2, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5, 4, 6, 0]}, 2: {0: [0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 9], 1: [5, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 3], 2: [1, 6, 5, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, the problem is you use same `temp` for all.

So just move statement `temp = {}` after `for x in range(3):`

```py
import numpy as np

d = {}
for x in range(3):
    temp = {}
    for i in range(3):
        temp[i] = list(np.random.randint(10, size=10))
    print(x)
    print(temp)
    d[x] = temp
    print(d[x])
print("--------------------------")
print("The final dictionary: ", d)
```

Comment: So basically, I need to make a new object every time otherwise it will assign only the last instance of the object. This would make sense combined with @FloLie answer since it's the same logic but just with copy(). Thank you!

Comment: In your code, not last instance, but same and the only one dictionary `temp`.